# Realizar consultas a BD SQL y hacer fetch si se escriben minusculas o mayusculas

Tags: php, sql

Debo realizar una consulta a mi base de datos en la cual ya ha sido registrado un dato en un campo, y al momento de realizar la búsqueda por medio de una interfaz desarrollada en **PHP** encuentre dicho registro, hasta aquí todo bien, pero sumándole a eso el usuario podrá escribir el nombre de su búsqueda con mayúsculas o minúsculas y la consulta deberá traer el dato requerido, aunque el registro no se encuentre con dichos caracteres como las mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Ejemplo del query que realizo a mi BD SQL:

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, last_name, email FROM $tabla WHERE email = :email");
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datos["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
```

esta consulta es enviada a partir de un campo input en mi interfaz el cual posee un formulario que envía por POST el dato, en mi BD tendría un registro así:

correo-e@correo.com, mientras que mi busqueda sería **C**orreo-e@correo.com, C en mayúscula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente la solución más factible teniendo en cuenta que ya mi base de datos contenía varios registros es al traer el dato solicitado y compararlo con el que el usuario ingresa por el formulario ambos se les aplica la función strtoupper(), la cual convierte ambas entradas en mayúsculas.

```
if(strtoupper($busqueda) == strtoupper($resultado)){}
```

y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Haz un upper en ambos lados y así evitas el problema de mayusculas/minusculas

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, last_name, email FROM $tabla WHERE UPPER(email) = UPPER(:email)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datos["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: intenté realizarlo de esa manera pero el resultado es igual al momento de realizar la consulta me arroja como resultado que el usuario no existe, si es escrito tal cual está el registro en BD si responde como correcto. alguna idea de que puede ser ?

Comment: Prueba a ejecutar la consulta directamente sobre la BBDD a ver si te lo devuelve.

Comment: directamente en la BD realizando la consulta por SQL me trae el resultado , sin embargo al ejecutarlo en mi programa, continúa mostrando el mismo error, el query se encuentra así: 

`$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, role_id, nombre, last_name, walletCelular, email, password, activado FROM $tabla WHERE UPPER(email) = UPPER(':email')");
  $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datosModel["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();`

El parametro que le paso por PDO lo dejo entre comillas ya que en ocasiones los correos no son tomados correctamente al enviar la consulta.

Comment: Tecnicamente las comillas no serian necesarias, prueba sin ellas a ver si es que estan interfiriendo.

Comment: siento decir que sigue sin funcionar. algo en la consulta sql no está recibiendo correctamente los datos o la función

Comment: ¿El nombre del parametro en el bindParam tiene que llevar ':'? . Se que en otros lenguajes no pero en php no recuerdo ahora.

Comment: también lo he intentado enviando directamente una variable que toma el valor del campo email del arreglo que le envío.
`UPPER(email) = UPPER($email)`

Comment: Si lo haces de esa forma creo que si tiene que llevar comillas `UPPER(email) = UPPER('$email')`. Hazlo solo para probar pues poniendolo directamente con la variable es vulnerable a inyeccion sql.

Comment: si claro en este caso he puesto las comillas simples, por el tipo de dato que envío. posiblemente deba utilizar otra función para ello.

Comment: Puedes poner el diseño de tu tabla a ver si vemos algo en ella.

Answer (score 0):

Sanchez prueba insertando el **UPPER**, te dejo como sería tu query:

**SELECT id, nombre, last_name, email FROM $tabla WHERE UPPER(email) = UPPER(:email)**

Con eso estaría resuelto tu consulta, así envíen los datos con o sin mayúsculas

Saludos

Comment: intenté realizarlo de esa manera pero el resultado es igual al momento de realizar la consulta me arroja como resultado que el usuario no existe, si es escrito tal cual está el registro en BD si responde como correcto. alguna idea de que puede ser ?

Comment: Ejecutalo la consulta desde tu SQL y prueba si te funciona.

Comment: functiona pero desde mi programa no

Comment: `$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, role_id, nombre, last_name, walletCelular, email, password, activado FROM $tabla WHERE UPPER(email) = UPPER(':email')"); $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datosModel["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR); $stmt->execute();`